# ionic constructor parameter cannot be accessed in method

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, parameters, constructor

I use navCtrl to push data from one component which is a table and use navParams to get data in another component which is to calculate sum of column numbers in table.

Code in first component: (TableInputComponent)

```
    onTableCellUpdated(updatedTableCell: TableCell) {
        //this.logger.info(this.Label + 'onTableCellUpdated updatedTableCell:')
        //this.logger.info(updatedTableCell)
    
        // update gridRowJSON first - maintain data structure for displaying table
        this.gridRowJSON[updatedTableCell.indexOfGridRowJSON][updatedTableCell.Header] = updatedTableCell.Data1;
        //this.logger.info(this.Label + 'onTableCellUpdated this.gridRowJSON:')
        //this.logger.info(this.gridRowJSON)
        //this.logger.info(this.rows)
    
        // update here to trigger update for table-input-cell
        let updatingRow = this.rows[updatedTableCell.rowIndex]
        if (updatedTableCell.InputType === this.UI_TYPE_CHECKBOX) {
          updatingRow.filter(cell => cell.Header === updatedTableCell.Header)[0].Data1
            = updatedTableCell.Data1
          updatingRow.filter(cell => cell.Header === updatedTableCell.Header)[0].IsChecked
            = updatedTableCell.Data1 === updatedTableCell.InputAttribute.split('_')[0]
    
          // only uncheck other checkbox if selecting checkbox is checked
          // prevent coming to this function again when other checkbox is unchecked
          if (updatedTableCell.IsChecked && this.Data1) {
            updatingRow.filter(cell =>
              cell.Header !== updatedTableCell.Header
              && cell.InputType === 'CHECKBOX'
              && cell.InputWritable)
              .forEach(cell => {
                //this.logger.info(this.Label + 'onTableCellUpdated other CHECKBOX cell:')
                //this.logger.info(cell)
                cell.Data1 = ''
                cell.IsChecked = false
              });
          }
        }
      this.Data1 = this.getSubmitJSON() 

   this.emitUserInput(TableInputComponent, this.Data1);

}
```

Code in second component:(CalculatorInputTableComponent)

```
public tableData: any

  constructor(public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.tableData = this.navParams.get('tableData')
    this.logger.info("data1->",  this.tableData)
}

calculate() {
  this.logger.info("data2->",  this.tableData)
}
```

When I input data in table, the first component will pass data to the second component, so I will see the logger show data1 value because it has been passed into the constructor.
But when I run the "calculate()" function, the logger will show data2 is "undefined"

it seems I cannot access the parameter "tableData" in constructor from the calculate() method.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me from where you called the calculate() function?

Comment: The table and the display of calculate result are in same page, I added a calculate button besides the calculate result to call the calculate() function.

Comment: Okay. Can you share your table code so I can check and help to fix this problem?

Comment: I updated in my post. But I think my issue is just how to pass data from one component to another component, when these two components are in same page. I used the navController and navParams, but it seems for passing data between pages, not within one page. And another problem is how to access variables in constructor from a method. I can only use navParams in constructor to get the data, I cannot get data if I write navParams in method.

Comment: Passing data through components can best be done with a service. Look up angular service and then u can initialize the service in your component and call the data.

Comment: @Mounir OK, I'll do some research. Thanks

Comment: @darkfruitmilk if you can't figure it out just tag me again and i'll take a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to pass data into multiple objects:

[Angular service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MessageService {
  messages: string[] = [];

  add(message: string) {
    this.messages.push(message);
  }

  clear() {
    this.messages = [];
  }
}
```

The example is just a copy from the angular doc API.

Call your service like this in your components:

```
constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }
```

Afterwards you should be able to call the methods/data you saved in a service.

Quick tip about services, they stay alive once you start them up. Unlike a component that gets destroyed. If you want to reset your data when your components reopens you have to set in your code.